# PHP: MySQL query duplicating update for no reason

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

The code below is first the client code, then the class file.

For some reason the 'deductTokens()' method is calling twice, thus charging an account double.
I've been programming all night, so I may just need a second pair of eyes:

```
    if ($action == 'place_order') {

    if ($_REQUEST['unlimited'] == 200) {

        $license = 'extended';

    } else {

        $license = 'standard';

    }

    if ($photograph->isValidPhotographSize($photograph_id, $_REQUEST['size_radio'])) {

        $token_cost = $photograph->getTokenCost($_REQUEST['size_radio'], $_REQUEST['unlimited']);
        $order = new ImageOrder($_SESSION['user']['id'], $_REQUEST['size_radio'], $license, $token_cost);
        $order->saveOrder();
        $order->deductTokens();
        header('location: account.php');

    } else {

        die("Please go back and select a valid photograph size");

    }

}


######CLASS CODE#######
<?php

include_once('database_classes.php');

class Order {

    protected $account_id;
    protected $cost;
    protected $license;

    public function __construct($account_id, $license, $cost) {

        $this->account_id = $account_id;
        $this->cost = $cost;
        $this->license = $license;

    }

}

class ImageOrder extends Order {

    protected $size;

    public function __construct($account_id, $size, $license, $cost) {

        $this->size = $size;

        parent::__construct($account_id, $license, $cost);

    }

    public function saveOrder() {

        //$db = Connect::connect();
        //$account_id = $db->real_escape_string($this->account_id);
        //$size = $db->real_escape_string($this->size);
        //$license = $db->real_escape_string($this->license);
        //$cost = $db->real_escape_string($this->cost);

    }

    public function deductTokens() {

        $db = Connect::connect();
        $account_id = $db->real_escape_string($this->account_id);
        $cost = $db->real_escape_string($this->cost);
        $query = "UPDATE accounts set tokens=tokens-$cost WHERE id=$account_id";
        $result = $db->query($query);

    }

}

?>
```

When I die("$query"); directly after the query, it's printing the proper statement, and when I run that query within MySQL it works perfectly.

$action = $_REQUEST['action'];

account.php is just a list of orders, never does it call up downloads.php.  Just tried commenting out the redirect, but I'm having the same problem.  I don't understand how it's getting called twice, the die statements are showing the right query, and the script doesn't reload itself.

Here are my apache access logs:

```
71.*** - - [22/May/2010:13:14:35 +0000] "POST /download.php?action=confirm_download&photograph_id=122 HTTP/1.1" 200 1951 "http://***.com/viewphotograph.php?photograph_id=122" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
71.***  - - [22/May/2010:13:14:36 +0000] "GET /download.php?action=place_order&photograph_id=122&size_radio=xsmall&unlimited=0 HTTP/1.1" 302 453 "http://*** .com/download.php?action=confirm_download&photograph_id=122" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
71.***  - - [22/May/2010:13:14:36 +0000] "GET /download.php?action=place_order&photograph_id=122&size_radio=xsmall&unlimited=0 HTTP/1.1" 302 453 "http://*** .com/download.php?action=confirm_download&photograph_id=122" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
71.***  - - [22/May/2010:13:14:36 +0000] "GET /account.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2626 "http://***.com/download.php?action=confirm_download&photograph_id=122" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
```

I understand there's obviously something wrong here.  But I can't figure out where the second request is coming from.

Comment: Debugging is always better than pair of eyes. Code intended to be run, not to be looked into.

Comment: I've been trying to run this code for four hours.  I haven't slept for 36 hours.

Comment: If I put a die("$query"); right before result, it displays the right query. If I put it right after $result, it shows the right query still, but the wrong amount still gets deducted.

Comment: Well sometimes debugging take me even more time. I'm just pointing to the obvious fact that it's almost impossible to debug your code without the the full code, database ans environment.

Comment: You should using (and requiring) a POST request for anything that changes state, like placing an order. Apart from all the usual reasons, this also makes it harder to accidentally submit twice :-)

Comment: BOBINCE -  Please create this into an answer so I can accept it.  Apparently using the 'get' method was causing the script to run twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another long shot, but it happened to me once in Firefox - doubled page executions, resulting in doubled inserts and updates - close your browser and restart.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
header('location: account.php');
```

Forwards the browser, but **doesn't end the php script**.
This might be fine, the code-snippet you gave doens't "do" anything after this line.

Another option might be a **double-click**
If you double-click on the submit button, the form will be sent twice.
We used some javascript to disable the submit button after the first click.

Comment: I already tried adding a return 0; after the redirect.  And I'm making sure to only click once.

Answer (score 0):

I know this will sound strange but make sure that you don't have  tag with empty src="" attribute or any css style refering to empty url (like background: url();) on your site around the place when you have your code that runs twice.

Read about some trouble this may cause here: http://hi.baidu.com/zhenyk/blog/item/38a1051fc63b96c3a686698f.html

Comment: I had similar problem where a counter was being updated twice per request, ended up with a JavaScript error in a slideshow!