# Mysql Update query is executing twice in chrome but once in mozilla

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having very different problem that i have written one query which should execute only once on page load but it is getting executed twice in chrome. Does any body have any idea regarding this issue.

I have also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887989/php-mysql-query-duplicating-update-for-no-reason) link but its of no use for me.

My Code :

```
// $rowvo['od_qty']=10;

// $row_1['qty']=20;

$sql = "SELECT qty  FROM tbl_size WHERE size_id =".$rowvo['size_id'];

$result = dbQuery($sql);

$row_1    = dbFetchAssoc($result);

$pqty=$row_1['qty']-$rowvo['od_qty'];

echo "Total Quantity Available Before Diduction : ".$row_1['qty'];

echo "Sold Quantity : ".$rowvo['od_qty'];

echo "Remaining Quantity : $pqty";

$sql_qty="update tbl_size set `qty`=$pqty where `size_id`=".$rowvo['size_id'];

echo "$sql_qty<br>";

$result_qty=mysql_query($sql_qty) or die('Error : '.mysql_error());

echo "No of Rows Affected : ".mysql_affected_rows()."<br>".mysql_error(); // 1
```

Error Log on Webserver :

```
[Wed Oct 09 12:19:30 2013] [notice] cannot use a full URL in a 401 ErrorDocument directive --- ignoring!
[Wed Oct 09 12:19:32 2013] [notice] cannot use a full URL in a 401 ErrorDocument directive --- ignoring!
[Wed Oct 09 12:19:32 2013] [notice] cannot use a full URL in a 401 ErrorDocument directive --- ignoring!
```

Comment: Cooooooooooooooode?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP nor MySQL but rather HTML/JS, right? As MySQL is never executed on a browser.

Comment: @Samuel But that HTML or JS may be causing the PHP to execute twice, of course.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart sure but tagging it with php and mysql won't help as this is probably a JS issue rather than php/mysql. But as long as OP does not provide more information this is guesswork.

Comment: @Samuel : i'm not using ajax....my php code is embed with other HTML code and js code

Comment: Ok so can we see that code?

Comment: @Pankaj you are experiencing different behaviour in different browsers. The thing that typically runs in a browser is javascript which causes duplicate calls to php which then calls duplicate calls to mysql. I guess your javascript is wrong.

Comment: @Samuel But he said he's not using ajax...

Comment: Pankaj don't waste your time explaining in comments what it is, you are running out of it. Soon this question will get closed, better post your code in your question so others can see if anything is wrong with it. Comments can come later

Comment: Ok great, now is there any javascript code as well?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky : I'm having JS libraries(e.g. lightbox.js) included but i'm not using any js function on this page and also i don't have any js error on console panel.

Comment: Is any chrome debugger extension enabled? that might be sending two requests to the server. Check Your web server logs

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky :  No I don't have any chrome debugger extension enabled and i have updated my error log please check it out.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky : is it possible that this kind of problem can only be occur on localhost and not on live server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue of multiple execution of the same query is because of broken style tag

```
style='background-image:url()';
```

But i didn't understood how can above thing has impact on my php code??????