# CodeIgniter update query gets executed twice

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am using CodeIgniter 2.2.

I have to update database with +1 every time a page is visited. Code works but it get incremented by +2 every time.

Example: if `total views=2`, once the page is clicked `total views` should be `3`, but the value in the database is `4`.

I am sure that I am calling the model `add_one_to_view_image` only once in my controller.

**controller**

```
   function view(){

    $view_id =  $this->uri->segment(3);

    if($view_id){
        $this->property->add_one_to_view_image($view_id);
        $prop['prop_detail'] = $this->property->get_single_property_for_view($view_id);
        $prop['prop_imgs'] = $this->property->get_single_property_images($view_id);
        $prop['amenities'] = $this->property->get_single_property_amenities($view_id);
        $prop['latest'] =  $this->home->get_latest_properties();

        $size = sizeof($prop['latest']);
        for($k=0; $k< $size; $k++){
        $Image_name = $this->property->get_property_first_image($prop['latest'][$k]->property_id);
            if($Image_name){
            $prop['latest'][$k]->image=$Image_name[0]->name;
            }else {
                $prop['latest'][$k]->image="";
            }
        }


    $this->load->view('property_view', $prop); 
    }

}
```

**Model**

```
  function add_one_to_view_image($id){

  echo "We in add one to views";
  $this->db->where('property_id', $id);
  $this->db->set('views', 'views+1', FALSE);
  $this->db->update('property_views'); 
 }
```

I added a echo statement inside the model. and it prints only once..

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en-US">
            <head>

                <?php $this->load->view('header_links'); ?>


                <title><?php echo $prop_detail[0]->title; ?> | lanka Property</title>
                <meta name="author" content="Sathyabaman - lankaproperty.com">
                <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $prop_detail[0]->full_description; ?>">
                <meta name="keywords" content="home, land, apartment, house, room, Commercial Building, buy, sell, rent, lease, sri lanka">


            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="wrapper-outer" >
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="wrapper-inner">
                        <?php $this->load->view('header_top_user_bar'); ?>
                        <?php $this->load->view('header_logo'); ?>
                        <?php $this->load->view('navigation'); ?>


                        <!-- CONTENT -->
                        <div id="content"><div class="container">
                <div id="main">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span9">
                            <h1 class="page-header"><?php echo $prop_detail[0]->title; ?></h1>

                            <div class="carousel property">
                                <div class="preview">
                                        <li class="active">
                                            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/upload_images/<?php echo $prop_imgs[0]->name; ?>" alt="">
                                        </li>

                                </div><!-- /.preview -->

                                <div class="content">

                                    <a class="carousel-prev" href="#">Previous</a>
                                    <a class="carousel-next" href="#">Next</a>
                                    <ul>

                                        <?php foreach ($prop_imgs as $img) : ?>
                                        <li class="active">
                                            <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/upload_images/<?php echo $img->name; ?>" alt="">
                                        </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.content -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.carousel -->



                            <div class="property-detail">
                                <div class="pull-left overview">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="span3">
                                            <h2>Overview</h2>

                                    <?php foreach ($prop_detail as $dtl) : ?>

                                            <table>

                                                <tr>


                                                    <?php   if($dtl->status == 0){?>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 120%;"><strong>Under Approval</strong></td>
                                                    <?php } if($dtl->status == 1){?>
                                                    <td style="color:green; font-size: 200%;"><strong>Available!</strong></td>
                                                    <?php } if($dtl->status == 2){?>
                                                    <td style="color:red; font-size: 200%;"><strong>Expired!</strong></td>
                                                    <?php } if($dtl->status == 3){?>
                                                    <td style="color:red; font-size: 200%;"><strong>Deleted!</strong></td>
                                                    <?php } if($dtl->status == 4){?>
                                                    <td style="color:red; font-size: 200%;"><strong>Suspended!</strong></td>
                                                    <?php } ?>

                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                    <td><br/></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                 <tr>
                                                    <th>Property ID :</th>
                                                    <td> PPTID<?php echo $dtl->property_id; ?></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Price :</th>
                                                    <td><?php if($dtl->price == 0){ echo "negotiable"; }
                                                                else {
                                                                    $price_text = (string)$dtl->price; // convert into a string
                                                                    $arr = str_split($price_text, "3"); // break string in 3 character sets
                                                                    $price_new_text = implode(",", $arr);  // implode array with comma

                                                                    echo 'Rs. '.$price_new_text.'/='; 

                                                                } ?>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Property type :</th>
                                                    <td><?php echo $dtl->type_name; ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Property size :</th>
                                                    <td><?php echo $dtl->size; ?>  <?php echo $dtl->size_type; ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Contract type :</th>
                                                    <td><?php echo $dtl->contract_type; ?></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <?php if($dtl->bed){ ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Bedrooms :</th>
                                                    <td><?php echo $dtl->bed; ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php } if($dtl->bath){ ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Bathrooms :</th>
                                                    <td><?php echo $dtl->bath; ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php } if($dtl->address){?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>address :</th>
                                                    <td><?php echo $dtl->address; ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Area :</th>
                                                    <td><?php echo $dtl->area; ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>City :</th>
                                                    <td><?php echo $dtl->city; ?></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <?php if($dtl->Contact_name){ ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Contact Name :</th>
                                                    <td><?php echo $dtl->Contact_name; ?></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php } ?>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Contact No 1 :</th>
                                                    <td><strong><?php echo chunk_split($dtl->phone_home, 3, ' '); ?></strong></td>
                                                </tr>

                                                <?php if($dtl->phone_hand){ ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Contact No 2 :</th>
                                                    <td><strong><?php echo chunk_split($dtl->phone_hand, 3, ' '); ?></strong></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <?php } ?>

                                                <tr><td colspan="2">
                                                <br/>
                                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large list-your-property">
                                                 Contact : <?php echo chunk_split($dtl->phone_home, 3, ' '); ?></a>
                                                </td></tr>

                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /.span2 -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.row -->
                                </div>

                                <p><?php echo nl2br($dtl->full_description); ?>.</p>


                            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <br/><br/>
                                <h2>General amenities</h2>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <ul class="span2">
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Gym==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Gym
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Air_conditioning==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Air Conditioning
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->internet==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Internet
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Wifi==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Wifi
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Lift==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Lift
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Furnished==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Furnished
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="span2">
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Television==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Television
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Hot_Water==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Hot Water
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Smoking_allowed==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Smoking Allowed
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Pets_allowed==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Pets Allowed
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Garage==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Garage
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Secure_parking==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Secure parking
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="span2">
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Swimming_Pool==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Swimming Pool
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Tennis_court==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Tennis court
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Balcony==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Balcony
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Fenced==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Fenced
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Back_up_Generator==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Back Up Generator
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Garden==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Garden
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="span2">
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Waterfront==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Waterfront
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Ocean_View==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Ocean View
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Security==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Security
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="<?php if($amenities[0]->Water_Tank==1){echo 'checked'; }else{echo 'plain';} ?>">
                                            Water Tank
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                                <!--
                                <h2>Map</h2>

                                <div id="property-map"></div> -->

                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="sidebar span3">




            <div class="widget contact">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2 class="block-title">Contact Owner</h2>
                </div><!-- /.title -->

                <div class="content">
                    <form method="post" id="frm_contact_owner">

                        <div class="alert alert-success" id="co_sucess_message"  style="display: none">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                            <strong>Message successfully send to owner!. <br/>Thank you!</strong>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="co_property_id" value="<?php echo $dtl->property_id; ?>">

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" >
                                Name
                                <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span>
                                <span class="form-required" id="co_name_error" title="This field is required."></span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" name="co_name" id="co_name">
                            </div><!-- /.controls -->
                        </div><!-- /.control-group -->

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" >
                                Email
                                <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span>
                                <span class="form-required" id="co_email_error" title="This field is required."></span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text"  name="co_email" id="co_email">
                            </div><!-- /.controls -->
                        </div><!-- /.control-group -->

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" >
                                Message
                                <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span>
                                <span class="form-required" id="co_message_error" title="This field is required."></span>
                            </label>

                            <div class="controls">
                                <textarea name="co_message" id="co_message"></textarea>
                            </div><!-- /.controls -->
                        </div><!-- /.control-group -->

                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <input type="submit" id="co_send" class="btn btn-primary arrow-right" value="Send">
                             <img id="co_ajax_image" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>html/assets/img/ajax_loader.gif" alt="" style="float: left; display:none">
                        </div><!-- /.form-actions -->
                    </form>
                </div><!-- /.content -->
            </div><!-- /.widget -->


            <div class="widget properties last">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>Latest Properties</h2>
                </div><!-- /.title -->

                <div class="content">


                <?php foreach ($latest as $latest_pro) :?>

                    <div class="property">
                        <div class="image">
                            <?php
                            if($latest_pro->image){ 
                                $image_name = base_url().'upload_images/'.$latest_pro->image;
                            }else{
                                $image_name = base_url().'html/assets/img/tmp/property-small-5.png';
                            }
                            ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>property/view/<?php echo $latest_pro->property_id; ?>/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_', $latest_pro->title); ?>"></a>
                            <img src="<?php echo $image_name; ?>"  alt="">
                        </div><!-- /.image -->

                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="title">
                                <h3>
                                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>property/view/<?php echo $latest_pro->property_id; ?>/<?php echo str_replace(' ', '_', $latest_pro->title); ?>"><?php echo substr($latest_pro->title, 0, 16); ?>..</a>
                                </h3>
                            </div><!-- /.title -->
                            <div class="location"><?php echo $latest_pro->area; ?>, <?php echo $latest_pro->city; ?></div><!-- /.location -->
                            <div class="price">
                            <?php if($latest_pro->price == 0){ echo "negotiable"; }
                                  else {
                                    $price_text = (string)$latest_pro->price; // convert into a string
                                    $arr = str_split($price_text, "3"); // break string in 3 character sets
                                    $price_new_text = implode(",", $arr);  // implode array with comma

                                    echo 'Rs. '.$price_new_text.'/='; 

                                } ?>
                            </div><!-- /.price -->
                        </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
                    </div><!-- /.property -->

                <?php endforeach; ?>



                </div><!-- /.content -->
            </div><!-- /.properties -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                </div><!-- /#content -->
            </div><!-- /#wrapper-inner -->

                <?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>

            </div><!-- /#wrapper -->
            </div><!-- /#wrapper-outer -->

                <?php $this->load->view('footer_setting_palette'); ?>
                <?php //$this->load->view('property_filter_ajax'); ?>
                <?php $this->load->view('say_hello_ajax'); ?>
                <?php $this->load->view('property_contact_owner'); ?>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: 2 -> 5 is an increase of 3, are you calling the model function anywhere else? did you declare in multiple spots by chance?

Comment: Tnx i changed it. no i am sure, am calling the model `add_one_to_view_image` only once in the whole application.

Comment: then you call that place multiple times.. but isn't it trivial to debug how many times a function gets called?

Comment: I would log or otherwise protocol all sql queries (depends on rdbms) to see if this gets multiple times or it gets incremented by 2 somehow. Not knowing your framework, try writing `$newvalue = $resultset[0]->views + 1` instead.

Comment: i did many application using codiginator, all the application i faced the same problem

Comment: @StephanB i tried that one, that also gives the same result, no change.

Comment: add an exit before the function ends, See if you still go up by 2

Comment: @exussum, worked. but the application stopped from loading..( view didn’t load)..

Comment: Your function is very clearly being called twice then, Work out when its being called the second time and fix it

Comment: Have you inspected web server logs to make sure you do not load page twice in a row?

Comment: Maybe you call `add_one_to_view_image` in your model too thougth `$this->add_one_to_view_image`

Comment: nope. am sure i have `add_one_to_view_image` i am sure i am calling it only once in the whole application. i checked it twice..

Comment: Post your view and layout

Comment: i Added my full View.

Comment: Do you have a online example we could check ?

Comment: The only possible reason, I can come with is that your page is requested multiple time, one reason can be that you have image with empty `src`, that will make request to the same page again, or may be some sort of ajax request being called from the page, check access log for number of requests

Comment: Checkout Chrome developer tools -> network if there are some request by ajax on that page... I think second increment makes ajax call...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know it's completly illlogical but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264616/mysql-update-query-is-executing-twice-in-chrome-but-once-in-mozilla) out....

I had also got the same issue long back but after 1 week of headache I come to know about this solution.

I got the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887989/php-mysql-query-duplicating-update-for-no-reason) link, check out the 2nd answer. Initially I also didn't take that solution seriously but in the end it worked for me :)

Solution :

Make sure you don't have tag with empty src="" attribute or any css style refering to empty url (like background: url();) on your site around the place when you have your code that runs twice.

Comment: Hi @Pankaj, could you include the relevant parts of your links in your answer please? That way, if they go down, or are blocked by firewall, etc., your answer is still useful. Thanks.

Comment: Beat me to it, this is my opinion from experience. As suggested by a comment on main post by Alik, check your web server access logs. Load the page *once*, then see if you get *two* accesses on your web server. Chances are yes, in which case you may have a bad script/link/img tag that loads your current page a second time. This is the case 90% of the time this problem occurs. If not, you application has a bug and I would suggest running a debugger (ex: xdebug) to walk through your code's execution path to see where the second call is coming from in one request.

Answer (score 1):

try this solution, i have also done this same in my project and didn't face any problem. if i see logically there is no problem with your code but just try row() instead of result() function and than see if it have the same impact. and make sure default value of the column view is 0

```
  function add_one_to_view_image($id){

  $this->db->select('views');
  $this->db->from('property_views');
  $this->db->where('property_id', $id);
  $pag = $this->db->get();        
  $resultset = $pag->row();

  $newvalue = ++$resultset->views;

  $data = array('views' => $newvalue);
  $this->db->where('property_id', $id);
   $this->db->update('property_views', $data); 
 }
```

when you are going to get 1 row is bettery to get it by row rather than getting it as a result.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can make the incrementation directly in active record :

Refering to the [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) :

> **set()** will also accept an optional third parameter ($escape), that
>   will prevent data from being escaped if set to FALSE.

So the `views+1`will not be escaped and the query will work correctly :

```
function add_one_to_view_image($id){
    $this->db->where('property_id', $id);
    $this->db->set('views', 'views+1', FALSE);
    $this->db->update('property_views');
}
```

Comment: It still incrementing by 2 ? So this function is called twice. This is the best way to increment a field stored in a database.

Comment: Even if it does not fix the problem, it performs better under heavy load and still give correct numbers unlike select + update...

Answer (score 0):

Check your webserver access log. My guess is that you're calling your page twice... Either from a bad link (empty src), redirect to it on a 404 (missing favicon?) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem when i'm making a view counter it's getting incremented multiple times.

then i came up with the solution to use $this->db->cache_delete_all();

```
function add_one_to_view_image($id){
       $this->db->cache_delete_all();
       $this->db->where('property_id', $id);
       $this->db->set('views', 'views+1', FALSE);
       $this->db->update('property_views'); 
}
```

But in my senario i was using direct query eg:

```
$this->db->query("Update settings set option_value = '{$newCounter}' where option_name = 'counter'");
```

Hope it will fix your problem.